# R Averaged vector field

Tags: r, vector, plot, field, average

I have a lot of 2D vectors represented by beginning (x1;y1) and end coordinates (x2;y2). I am able to plot them. I use R for that. The result is an unintelligible mess. The vectors begin and end in an irregular way, cross over, some are tiny some are long etc. Is there a simple way to plot a vector field with regular/same distances between the begginings of vectors by adding or averaging vectors in same regular small probably square areas of the picure to get nice vector field?
Thanks
T.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I have what I have understood is correct or not. But if given a rectangular area with (x1,y1) as top left coordinates and (x2, y2) as bottom right coordinates, and you want to show a rectangular patch, and if you are coding in matlab/octave then you can use

`plot([x1 x2 x2 x1 x1],[y1 y1 y2 y2 y1]);` to achieve what you want.

Comment: The (x1,y1) are just numbers/coordnates in 2D space of the beginning point and end point of each vector I use R mostly to draw the vector fields